# how can show photo in blade from database

Tags: laravel

I have a product with multiple photo that saved by json.

```
public function store(ProductRequest $request)
{
    if($request->hasfile('filename'))
     {

        foreach($request->file('filename') as $image)
        {
            $name=$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $year = Carbon::now()->year;
            $month = Carbon::now()->month;
            $day = Carbon::now()->day;
            $imagePath = "/upload/images/{$year}/{$month}/{$day}";
            $image->move(public_path($imagePath), $name);  
        $data[] = $imagePath . '/' . $name;
        }
     }

    product::create(array_merge($request->all() , ['images' => json_encode($data)]));
    $request->session()->flash('success', '!محصول با موفقیت ثبت شد');
    return redirect(route('Products.index'));
}
```

And my product how it is stored

```
#original: array:23 [▼
    "id" => 16
    "name" => "eqwsa"
    "code" => "۱۰۲۶"
    "price" => "۱۲۰۰۰۰"
    "slug" => "eqwsa"
    "description" => null
    "images" => "["\/upload\/images\/2020\/6\/15\/index222.jpg","\/upload\/images\/2020\/6\/15\/carpet4-1.jpg"]"
    "tags" => "eddsfew"
    "viewCount" => 0
    "commentCount" => 0
    "stockCount" => 0
    "sailedCount" => "0"
    "specialSail" => 0
    "specialPrice" => null
    "size_id" => 7
    "color_id" => 7
    "discount_id" => 7
    "yarn_id" => 1
    "category_id" => 10
    "density_id" => 4
    "comb_id" => 5
    "created_at" => "2020-06-15 12:04:55"
    "updated_at" => "2020-06-15 12:04:55"
  ]
```

in my Product model I specified that the images should be in the form of an array:

```
 protected $casts = [
    'images' => 'array',

];
```

How can I show all photo for this product in blade?

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly simple, you just loop through the array in your blade with an image tag. For example:

```php
foreach($product->images as $image) {
    <img src="{{$image}} alt="image text" />

}
```

This assumes you have done something like this in your view

```php
$product = YourProduct;
return view('product.show')->withProduct($product);
```

where `view()` parameter is the name of your blade.

You could consider adding media objects in its table with relation to the product, that way you can keep a structure of how your images should be, give them names, meta tags, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I do this way but this error is accured:Property [images] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Have you tried accessing it as an array with $product["images"] instead, might be returned as an array.